# Send email in background : Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using an inbuilt code in Laravel to send Email Notification. Code is below. I am using smtp to send email

```
class RegisterNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('hi');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Here the problem is, it takes around 5 seconds to complete the process and control does not come back. I am assuming that if it come back and do the email sending work in background...it would save a lot of time.

Is there any inbuilt work to do the same? I meant, control should come back and should say email sent...and then it should do the work in background.

**Email Sending code in Controller**

```
class apiRegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function Register(RegisterRequest $request) {

        $RegisterNotification = new RegisterNotification($Token);
        $User->notify($RegisterNotification);
    }
}
```

**Code for Queue**

**Controller Code**

```
$job = (new SendForgotPasswordEmail($Data))->onConnection('database');
dispatch($job);
```

**Job**

```
class SendForgotPasswordEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $Data;

    public $tries = 5;

    public function __construct($Data)
    {
        $this->Data = $Data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $Token = $this->Data["Token"];
        $User = $this->Data["User"];
        $RegisterNotification = new RegisterNotification($Token);
        $User->notify($RegisterNotification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** Change `class RegisterNotification extends Notification` to `class RegisterNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue`

**Step 2:** Implement a queue driver. In your `config/queue.php` make sure your driver is not set to sync like so: `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),` and make sure your .env doesnt have `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`. You can look at the [Laravel documentation for queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues) to choose an appropriate queue driver

Comment: I saw in `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),` in config/queue.php,  Should i remove it?

Comment: You need to set the queue driver to something other than sync. Available options include `database`, `beanstalkd`, `redis` and `sqs`. If you already have redis or beanstalkd installed choose either of them. If not you can always use `database`

Comment: Also checkout the driver prerequisites here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#driver-prerequisites

Comment: So far I have changed the env file and now it has `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` and in config/queue.php and finally I ran this statement `php artisan queue:table` and it created the jobs table. So far it seems good. Can you tell what should I do next for database?

Comment: I added the code in my question for the implementation done. I am finally getting an error: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword::$connection' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProjects\Projects\Learning\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender.php:158 Am I missing something?

Comment: did you run `php artisan migrate` after `php artisan queue:table`? Also, did you run `php artisan queue:work`. If you did both, good luck mate! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [build-in API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail).

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) use ($user){
      $message->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

      $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

But first you have to [configure the queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues).

Add in your .env file the line `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` and then write on the terminal `php artisan queue:listen`.

If you want the queue to run forever on the server use `Supervisor`. Queues documentation explains how you can use it.

Comment: From the Laravel doc: `a synchronous driver that will execute jobs immediately (for local use)`. The OP's problem is the 5 secs wait. A sync driver will not solve his problem

Comment: so what's the best way to use the `Mail:queue`?

Comment: The power of mail queue comes from the queue driver. A sync queue driver is as good as no queue. The most effective driver is beanstalkd, then redis and finally database (usually but could depend on your server and app architecture)

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel job queue https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

```
Mail::queue(
```